# Add a timed stop to javascript animation

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I am a noob. I was wondering how I could make this JS confetti animation last only 2 seconds? I see there is a start/stop function, but I am not entirely sure what to change those to. Any help would be most appreciated, thanks! Here's the code: https://codepen.io/iprodev/pen/azpWBr

```
            this.start = function() {
                this.stop()
                var context = this;
                this.update();
            }
            this.stop = function() {
                cAF(this.interval);
            }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setTimeout function.

Example:

```
this.start = function() {
    var context = this;
    this.update();
}
setTimeout(this.start(), 3000) // call function like this and it will wait 3 seconds(3000 miliseconds) before executing this.start function
```

Comment: Hmm, sadly this didn't work. I tried different construction of it, but could not get it to stop. Any other ideas looking at the code on codepen? Thank you!!

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with this

```
setTimeout(function() {
     confetti.stop();
  }, 2000);

Comment: Ok sorry I forgot to call function. I already edit my answer.